# Database schema design for network devices and configuration

Tags: sql, database-design, database-schema

I have the following database design problem:

Given the four entity types: `Interface`, `Device`, `VLAN`, `VNI`.

There are the following rules:

1. An `Interface` has exactly one `Device`. Consequently, a `Device` may have zero to many `Interfaces`.
2. An `Interface` can have zero to many `VLAN`s. A `VLAN` can have zero to many `Interfaces`. A `VLAN` cannot be assigned to the same `Interface` multiple times.
3. A `VLAN` can have zero or one `VNI`. Consequently a `VNI` has zero to many `VLAN`s.

So far this is easy, it can be modelled like this:

`Interface(id, device_id not null)`

`Device(id)`

`VLAN(id, vni_id nullable)`

`VNI(id)`

`InterfaceVLAN(interface_id not null, vlan_id not null) unique (interface_id, vlan_id)`

But there is a 4th rule: The tuple (`VNI`, `Device`, `VLAN`) must be unique.

It must also be possible to assign a `VLAN` to a `VNI` without that `VLAN` being assigned to an `Interface` or a `Device`. Also, a `VLAN` can be assigned to an `Interface` without the `VLAN` having a `VNI`.

I am stuck on how to incorporate this into the model and would welcome any suggestions.

Comment: In what way is this a "normalisation problem"? What have you applied to solving it that has to do with normalizing? [ask] [help]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the question:

> The tuple `(VNI, Device, VLAN)` must be unique.

From your comment to James Hu:

> Each VNI should map to no more than one VLAN on each Device.

These are two different constraints. The second one means that `(Device, VNI)` is unique, and it implies the first one, but not the other way around.

---

```
-- Vni tag VNI exists.
--
vni_tag {VNI}
     PK {VNI}


-- Virtual lan (vlan) VLN exists.
--
vlan {VLN}
  PK {VLN}
```

- Each vlan is mapped to *at most one* vni tag;
  for each vni tag, that tag *may* be mapped to *more than one* vlan.

```
-- Vlan VLN is mapped to vni tag VNI.
--
vln_vni {VLN, VNI}
     PK {VLN}
     SK {VLN, VNI}

FK1 {VLN} REFERENCES vlan    {VLN}
FK2 {VNI} REFERENCES vni_tag {VNI}
```

- Each device *may* have *more than one* interface;
  for each interface: that interface belongs to *exactly one* device.

```
-- Device DEV exists.
--
device {DEV}
    PK {DEV}


-- Interface number IFC# of device DEV exists.
--
interface {DEV, IFC#}
       PK {DEV, IFC#}

FK {DEV} REFERENCES device {DEV}
```

---

#### Unique  (DEV, VNI)

In the case of the second constraint, (DEV, VNI) unique:

- Each interface *may* be connected to *more than one* vlan;
  for each vlan, *more than one* interface  *may* be connected to that vlan.
- For each combination of device and vni tag, that combination of the device and the tag may occur at most once.

```
-- Interface number IFC# of device DEV is connected to
-- vlan VLN, which is mapped to vni tag VNI.
--
ifc_vln_vni {DEV, IFC#, VLN, VNI}
         PK {DEV, IFC#, VLN}
         AK {DEV, VNI}

FK1 {DEV, IFC#} REFERENCES interface {DEV, IFC#}
FK2 {VLN, VNI}  REFERENCES vln_vni   {VLN, VNI}
```

---

#### Unique  (DEV, VLN, VNI)

In the case of the first constraint, (DEV, VLN, VNI) unique:

- Each interface *may* be connected to *more than one* vlan;
  for each vlan, *more than one* interface  *may* be connected to that vlan.
- For each combination of device, vlan, and vni tag, that combination of the device, the vlan, and the tag may occur at most once.

```
-- Interface number IFC# of device DEV is connected to
-- vlan VLN, which is mapped to vni tag VNI.
--
ifc_vln_vni {DEV, IFC#, VLN, VNI}
         PK {DEV, IFC#, VLN}
         AK {DEV, VLN,  VNI}

FK1 {DEV, IFC#} REFERENCES interface {DEV, IFC#}
FK2 {VLN, VNI}  REFERENCES vln_vni   {VLN, VNI}
```

---

Note:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

```
Using suffix # to save on screen space.
OK for SQL Server and Oracle, for others use _NO.
For example, rename IFC# to IFC_NO.
```

Comment: Thanks a lot so far! Solution three, `unique (dev, vlan, vni)` is what I came up by myself as well, but it's not quite good enough: My user also wants to be able to assign `VLAN`s to `VNI`s without assigning them to an `Interface` (or a `Device`), and the constraint `PK(dev_id, iface_id, vlan_id)` prohibits that because then `dev_id` would be `null`. How can we fix that?

Comment: @Patrick Already done in `vln_vni`. Actually  mapping between vlan and vni must first exist in `vln_vni`. `VNI` in `ifc_vln_vni` is redundant, but needed in order to enforce required constraints. Or maybe I do not understand something.

Comment: And btw, all is `NOT NULL` in this model -- important.

Comment: Thank you for explaining! I think I have just one more question: how can I add a `VLAN` to an `Interface` that doesn't have a `VNI`?

Comment: @Patrick, (1/2) Not elegant, but VNI is 24 bit, hence it is possible to have another whole set of "none" (unique fake vni tags) represented by *negative numbers* within `bigint`. So when a new VLAN is created, it is by default mapped to a new unused fake VNI. These are later filtered out on the application level, or via DB views. The model with all constraints still works. Not my favorite, but may be the simplest depending on the DB used.

Comment: @Patrick (2/2) An elegant fix for *SQL Server* would be adding `ifc_vln` table and using an indexed view for `ifc_vln_vni` with *unique constraint* for the rule No 4 -- should work for *Oracle* too.  Triggers would be needed for *MySql, Maria DB, PostgreSQL, DB2*.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can try unique constraint. Assuming you have a `DEVICE` table which has a `DEVICE_ID` column as primary key and a 'VNI_ID` column as a foreign key, then you can just create a unique constraint on these two columns.

Comment: If I add a `vni_id` column as a foreign key on the `Device` table, I have data duplication for the relationship between `Device` and `VNI`, because now, a `VNI` can be attached to a `Device` through this foreign key, but also through `Device`->`Interface`->`VLAN`->`VNI`. So even if `device_id` and `vni_id` are unique on `Device` they might not be through `Device`->`Interface`->`VLAN`->`VNI`.

Comment: Now I get it. I looked up some context and this is my understanding:

Comment: This is my understanding: "No more than one VNI per DEVICE" seems to be a constraint your product manager wants to add, not how VNI was defined in the networking world. It introduces conflict or inconsistency to the original model defined by people who invented the concept of VNI. If this constraint is a must from application logic perspective, the validation of it should be implemented at application level, not RDBMS level.

Comment: The constraint is "the set of `VNI`s on a `Device` must be unique", not "only one `VNI` per `Device`". To put it another way: Each `VNI` should map to no more than one `VLAN` on each `Device`. Or another way still, the tuple (`VNI`, `VLAN`, `VNI`) must be globally unique. I have edited the question to make this clearer.